# little java help with loops

Tags: java

Hi I am doing some practice problems and trying to print a diagonal line like the example below. I have writen the program you see below and I honestly dont understand what I am doing wrong. I m a java beginner and I cant see how to find the error.

Example:

```
*
  *
    *
      *
        *
```

code:

```
class Diagonal{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int row, col;


    for(row = 1; row < 6; row++) {
      for(col = 1; col <= row; col++) {
          if(col==row){
            System.out.print("*");
          } else{
              System.out.print("");
          }
          System.out.println();     
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to learn for loops because they really confuse me. Another practice is to print a similar diagonal line but this time from right to left. I cant do that without getting this right however :( I believe they will be pretty similar?
Above my reasining is this: As long as the column # is the same as the row number the print the line or otherwise leave a blank....what's wrong with how i did it?

THANK YOU!

Comment: At first glance it looks like you just need to put the call to println after the "col" loop but inside the "row" loop. Also, it's customary to start loops at 0 instead of 1 (most of the time). I would also suggest moving the 'print("*")' outside the "col" loop, to make it a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 6):

You never print any space character. You print an empty String. Replace

```
System.out.print("");
```

with

```
System.out.print(" ");
```

Also, you write a newline after each column rather than writing one after each row.

Answer (score 2):

```
String spaces = "";

for(int row = 1; row < 6; row++) {
    System.out.println(spaces+"*");
    spaces += " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Print new lines when entering a star: `System.out.println("*");`
2. Add spaces:  `System.out.println(" ");`
3. remove the line where you print new lines between columns.

Comment: in fact, he prints a newline after each column, rather than printing one after each row.

Comment: Yes, you are right he should remove the last println() and add ln to the print(*) and it should work

Answer (score 0):

as said before replace black with space and move the end line to the end of the FIRST for() like this:

```
class Diagonal{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int row, col;


    for(row = 1; row < 6; row++) {
      for(col = 1; col <= row; col++) {
          if(col==row){
            System.out.print("*");
          } else{
              System.out.print(" ");
          }
      }
      System.out.println();     
    }
  }
}
```